# Are there any Facebook "suicide" apps out there?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I would like to delete a lot of my Facebook data without closing my account. Of course, doing it manually is a waste of time and it's not interesting :-)

Are there any services similar to http://suicidemachine.org/ that can help me achieve this?

A script, a website or an app of sorts would be excellent :-)

Answer (score 6):

There have been two web services to kill your social networks instantly.

- [Suicide Machine](http://suicidemachine.org/) (as you pointed out)
- [Seppukoo](http://www.seppukoo.com/)

Currently, both sites are blocked by Facebook. Actually, Seppukoo was killed itself some time ago.

Facebook took legal action against both services. So, at the moment, there is no any web app to kill your Facebook data. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Do you know what is the reason behind legal action against those services? Are developers not allowed to create bulk deletion apps?

Comment: Never mind, I read the cease and desist http://suicidemachine.org/download/Web_2.0_Suicide_Machine.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Because apps that delete user data get banned by Facebook very quickly, you will have to do it with something that lives *outside* FB.

[This page](http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html) details how to record a macro using a browser extension called iMacros:

- http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html

While the blog post itself is not being updated any longer, there are a number of scripts submitted by readers that are up-to-date.

The latest version there runs on Google Chrome and was posted by 'just an average someone' on June 4, 2011. (No permalinks for the comments, sorry - you'll have to Cmd+F)